# Sqli not creating tables in PHP code

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I am trying to see where the syntax is incorrect but this code won't make the following two tables, however, will make other small tables whose code I found online, such as

```
CREATE TABLE Persons
(
PersonID int,
LastName varchar(255),
FirstName varchar(255),
Address varchar(255),
City varchar(255)
);
```

But it won't make the two tables defined below in php code. Also,
`$mysqli` is the database connection object defined in other class that is required here.

```
<?php // Check connection
    $connectionStatus = FALSE;
    if (!$mysqli) {
       echo "<h2>Unable to connect to MySqli database!</h2>";
    } 
    else{
        echo "<h2>Successfully connected to MySqli database!</h2>";
        $connectionStatus = TRUE;
    }
    if($connectionStatus == TRUE){
         echo "<form action='' method='POST'>"; 
            echo "FLATFILE: <input type='file' name='FlatFile' /><br/><br/>";
            echo "<input type='submit'/>";
            echo "</form>";
    }
    if($connectionStatus == TRUE){
        $sql = "CREATE TABLE Supplier(
        Code varchar(255),
        Name varchar,
        Address1 varchar,
        Address2 varchar, 
        City varchar, 
        State varchar,
        Zip varchar,
        Country varchar,
        Phone varchar,
        Fax varchar,
        PRIMARY KEY (Code))";
        mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);

            $sql = "CREATE TABLE PO(
        Number varchar(255),
        ReceivingFactoryCode varchar,
        SupplierCode varchar,
        IssueYear varchar, 
        IssueMonth varchar, 
        IssueDay varchar,
        BuyingFactoryCode varchar,
        PRIMARY KEY (Number),
        FOREIGN KEY (ReceivingFactoryCode) REFERENCES Supplier(Code)
        )";
        mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);



    }


    $mysqli->close();

    ?>
```

Also for some reason, the following code that i found online works:

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE Persons
(
PersonID int,
LastName varchar(255),
FirstName varchar(255),
Address varchar(255),
City varchar(255)
)";
    mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);

 $sql = "CREATE TABLE Orders
(
O_Id int NOT NULL,
OrderNo int NOT NULL,
P_Id int,
PRIMARY KEY (O_Id),
FOREIGN KEY (P_Id) REFERENCES Persons(P_Id)
)";
mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
```

Comment: Are you getting *any* error messages?

Comment: No error messages; just that tables are not created. but when i use sql code found online and substitute for my tables, it works.

Comment: Check your error logs.

Comment: im using phpmyadmin to view the tables. does it have error logging?

Comment: No, your server does though.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: i have limited access to the server. i can only change a single database assigned to me.

Comment: @Jay I added your code after opening php tag and queried again but no error messages were shown.

Comment: could someone try to run this code on their server and let me know if its making the tables for them.

Comment: what if you echo your $SQL and do an insert in phpmyadmin, does it work then?

Comment: You have several `NOT NULL` declarations without a default value.

Comment: While the information contained in answers to "How to get mysqli error in different environments?" might have helped debug the initial problem, it has absolutely nothing to do with the root cause of the problem. I see no value in marking a 9 month old question with 45 views and an accepted answer, as duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try pasting the code into MySQL, if you are unable to configure logging correctly on your web server. You'd find that `varchar` is not a valid MySQL data type. Try `VARCHAR(255)` instead.

Comment: i don't know why but doing this and moving all attribute names in code to the left(formatting) fixed it.

Comment: You don't know why? I just told you why.